# Can't find reason for Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId when uploading to S3

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, sinatra

I searched Stack Overflow and the internet but haven't found an answer to this:

1. I have an EC2 instance running with lighttpd proxied to a Ruby Sinatra application running on Thin.
2. I have a bucket on S3 that I am attempting to upload to through the Sinatra application, the file is on my local machine, and I am using the Sinatra application running on EC2 to transmit the file into my S3 bucket.
3. I have my credentials setup in a .aws/credentials file as instructed by Amazon.

Each time I attempt to upload a file, whether through the Sinatra app or if I attempt to test a local file upload from the EC2 instance via the REPL, I receive the following error message:

```
Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidAccessKeyId The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

I setup a CORS config:

```
<CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Here is my Ruby code:

```
helpers do

  def upload(filename, file, credentials)
    bucket = 'BUCKET_NAME'
    region = 'us-west-2'

    s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: region, credentials: credentials)
    obj = s3.bucket(bucket).object(filename)
    obj.upload_file(file)
  end

end

get '/' do
  erb :index
end

get '/upload' do
  erb :upload
end

post '/upload' do
  file = params[:file][:tempfile]
  filename = params[:file][:filename]
  credentials = Aws::SharedCredentials.new
  upload(filename, file, credentials)
  redirect '/success'
end
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dissect the question:

- for the purpose of the upload, CORS does not matter. You are talking to S3 and uploading directly
- the credentials file needs to be in the ~/.aws/credentials where ~ is the home for the current user. What user is sinatra running under? Same user where the .aws/credentials are present?
- is the credentials file in the right format? It needs to be in an ini style and for what you're describing it needs to have access key and secret key (see sample below)
- if you take the credentials out of the file and do the call directly using the credentials does it work? (just from the error you might have a mix up here)
- have you considered using an ec2 role to push the credentials to the box and let EC2 and AWS SDK just do this work for you (i.e. you would not need to worry about credential rotation / permissions on every machine /etc)

Sample file:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = YOUR_ACCESS_KEY
aws_secret_access_key = YOUR_SECRET_KEY
```

Comment: Ah... I passed my credentials directly, as you suggested, and I found my problem! I was wrapping my init file values in single quotes when they needed to be bare.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! Now I will research the ec2 role, as you suggest :)

Comment: guys, I have issues with the secret key, invalidaccesskeyID. Just to be sure of what I've done: downloaded the CSV file from AWS, when new user is created. **Copy pasted** the access key and secret key as : aws_access_key_id = 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY' directly in python. It never worked! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -4):

Clearly you have deleted the access key ID or you are using the wrong access key ID, just go to your user settings or ask your admin to give you correct access key ID and access secret and attach proper policy with your account so that you may be able to upload to S3.

Hope this helps